# White frame in SKSprite animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, sprite-kit

I have all my animations in a single texture atlas. So far animations where working well, but I was using repeatActionForever. I tried creating a simple sequence for a one-time animation and I see a strange glitch the first time I run the animation. The last frame of the animation is completely white (not the X of missing image data). The code,

```
            removeAllActions()
            let anim0 = SKAction.animateWithTextures(frames0,
                timePerFrame: 0.2,
                resize: false,
                restore: true)
            let anim1 = SKAction.animateWithTextures(frames1, timePerFrame: 2.0)
            let seq = SKAction.sequence([anim0, anim1, SKAction.runBlock({self.animateIdle()})])
            self.runAction(seq,withKey:key.rawValue)
```

frames0 and frames1 are instantiate once when creating the object.
The first time I run this function, there's always a white frame between anim0 and anim1. If I replace anim1 for waitForDuration(1), I can see the white square for 1 sec.

The 2nd time I call the function, there's no glitch.
If I use repeatActionForever on the same frames, I don't see any glitch either.

It happens in both the simulator and a real device, and it's always on the first call after the creation of the object.

Any idea what may be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops...
It seems what I was seeing is the initial state of the sprite before any texture is loaded.

From the documentation of animateWithTextures:

> restore: When the action completes, the sprite’s texture is restored to the texture it had before the action completed. (If the resize parameter is YES, the sprite is resized to match the size of the original texture.)

That means that the first time I ran this, the sprite was "restored" to the initial white square (not sure why that's the original state... maybe a transparent sprite would be better?)

I changed restore to false and it fixes the issue :)

```
        let anim0 = SKAction.animateWithTextures(frames0,
            timePerFrame: 0.2,
            resize: false,
            restore: false)
```

Anyway, embarrassed that I didn't read the documentation properly... ^^;